# Cloud-Init Script Won't Run?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, infrastructure-as-code, ssh, cloud-init

I am working through this Terraform [tutorial](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/cloud-init?in=terraform/provision), which boots up a Go web app on an EC2 instance, using Terraform and cloud-init. This is my Terraform config file:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
  }
}


provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
}

data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-*20*-amd64-server-*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["099720109477"] # Canonical
}

resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block           = var.cidr_vpc
  enable_dns_support   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "igw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
}

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet_public" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  cidr_block = var.cidr_subnet
}

resource "aws_route_table" "rtb_public" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.igw.id
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "rta_subnet_public" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.subnet_public.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.rtb_public.id
}

resource "aws_security_group" "sg_22_80" {
  name   = "sg_22"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  # SSH access from the VPC
  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }


  ingress {
    from_port   = 8080
    to_port     = 8080
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = file("../scripts/add-ssh-web-app.yaml")
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami                         = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type               = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.subnet_public.id
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.sg_22_80.id]
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  user_data                   = data.template_file.user_data.rendered

  tags = {
    Name = "Learn-CloudInit"
  }
}

output "public_ip" {
  value = aws_instance.web.public_ip
}
```

My cloud-init script looks like this:

```
#cloud-config
# Add groups to the system
# Adds the ubuntu group with members 'root' and 'sys'
# and the empty group hashicorp.
#groups:
  - ubuntu: [root,sys]
  - hashicorp

# Add users to the system. Users are added after groups are added.
users:
  - default
  - name: terraform
    gecos: terraform
    shell: /bin/bash
    primary_group: hashicorp
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    groups: users, admin
    lock_passwd: false
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - ssh rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCMT6uYfhWx8jOmiGR9ryIPKcWy2ceqvyZ4
Q4+q5QTiZtlbWxbP37YZnT8uQhyjB4QRR1cjOyvGKC3Zu0Isy0eHIx2lGm/7B04b
soWWAUqhJmYWMZlivnHtJJJ4P5gnvXiRNmFg9iK07C7ClggNBAQZZHUeA5wcnvvH
T/pDkGUjMUqgLvmWRJqJM9qLT717e229F1Fyh+sYtAj08qmcFF1JCs2D33R46RQ8
YBMpQqmWLfjuJDUrjdvMu7Mv3aPpaeUWuYoC90iHR9XMeNonrtRlx21nY3CoMZ0A
OpeNl999UzyMJrsvN4qm6byK2Pc6jrEyKr9jI8SvMEGdSWgqr/Hd



# Downloads the golang package
packages:
  - golang-go

# Sets the GOPATH & downloads the demo payload
runcmd:
  - sudo su terraform
  - sudo mkdir /home/terraform/go
  - sudo chown terraform:hashicorp /home/terraform/go
  - export GOPATH=/home/terraform/go
  - go get github.com/hashicorp/learn-go-webapp-demo
```

After successfully applying the Terraform config, I obtain the following error when I try to SSH into this instance from the CLI using my OpenSSH private key:

*Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).*

To further investigate, I have SSH'd into the instance with AWS Direct Connect, from which I found none of the users, groups or directories had been created and the packages hadn't been installed - so it seems like the cloud-init script did not run at all. I'm guessing I can't SSH into my instance because the public key wasn't uploaded to it.

I assumed that this could be an issue with Ubuntu, so I changed the AMI to Linux 2, which resulted in the same error. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: this may just be stackexchange formatting so I wouldn't want to consider this a real answer. It's pretty important that the public key is formatted correctly.  I think yaml will munge your rsa key together, but can you try just removing the newlines?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues with this cloud-init script.

- `#groups` is commented out, so the list beneath it makes it invalid YAML.
- Even if we uncomment groups,   `- ubuntu: [root,sys]` is invalid because the default user already has a group specification. If you look near the bottom of `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` on a launched instance, you should see something like:

```yaml
system_info:
   # This will affect which distro class gets used
   distro: ubuntu
   # Default user name + that default users groups (if added/used)
   default_user:
     name: ubuntu
     lock_passwd: True
     gecos: Ubuntu
     groups: [adm, audio, cdrom, dialout, dip, floppy, lxd, netdev, plugdev, sudo, video]
     sudo: ["ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"]
     shell: /bin/bash
```

So you either need to remove the `ubuntu` line from your groups definition, or remove `- default` from your user definition and define the `ubuntu` user manually.

- Your ssh key is also pasted as invalid YAML. Keep it as a single line
- In your runcmd, `sudo su` doesn't work that way in a script. Instead you should `sudo -u <user>` for an individual user to run an individual command. Additionally, `sudo` isn't needed for root permissions as all user scripts run as root already.

Fixing all of these issues, we should get a resulting cloud-init script that looks something like this:

```yaml
#cloud-config

# Add the empty group hashicorp.
groups:
  - hashicorp

# Add users to the system. Users are added after groups are added.
users:
  - default
  - name: terraform
    gecos: terraform
    shell: /bin/bash
    primary_group: hashicorp
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    groups: users, admin
    lock_passwd: false
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - ssh rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCMT6uYfhWx8jOmiGR9ryIPKcWy2ceqvyZ4Q4+q5QTiZtlbWxbP37YZnT8uQhyjB4QRR1cjOyvGKC3Zu0Isy0eHIx2lGm/7B04bsoWWAUqhJmYWMZlivnHtJJJ4P5gnvXiRNmFg9iK07C7ClggNBAQZZHUeA5wcnvvHT/pDkGUjMUqgLvmWRJqJM9qLT717e229F1Fyh+sYtAj08qmcFF1JCs2D33R46RQ8YBMpQqmWLfjuJDUrjdvMu7Mv3aPpaeUWuYoC90iHR9XMeNonrtRlx21nY3CoMZ0AOpeNl999UzyMJrsvN4qm6byK2Pc6jrEyKr9jI8SvMEGdSWgqr/Hd

# Downloads the golang package
packages:
  - golang-go

# Sets the GOPATH & downloads the demo payload
runcmd:
  - mkdir /home/terraform/go
  - chown terraform:hashicorp /home/terraform/go
  - sudo GOPATH=/home/terraform/go -u terraform go install github.com/hashicorp/learn-go-webapp-demo@latest
```

Comment: I've used this cloud-init script, but I obtain the following error: Permission denied (publickey). I've ensured that I'm using the correct private key, in PEM format.

Comment: I copied what you initially provided, but every public RSA key I've seen starts with `ssh-rsa` not `ssh rsa`. Ensure you've copied the key correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it does not matter but also try to add "${}" around terraform's file function before rendering:

```
data "template_file" "init_script" {
  template = "${file("../scripts/add-ssh-web-app.yaml")}"
}
```